# Libcamera apps do not work

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

I'm on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye, using a Pi 3B. The error message is differing from the ones I could find on previous posts, and there are different fixes by changing `dtoverlay` in `/boot/config.txt`. Last time I re-enabled the Legacy stack camera at least that worked but it completely bugged the whole system, making it impossible to connect via VNC and many other unrelated things... I could not find a solution to this, here's what it tells me:

```
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:13:54.365083754] [3458]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3544-22656360
[0:13:54.405175545] [3474] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:591 'ov5647 10-0036': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[0:13:54.468034105] [3474]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1356 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:13:54.469572692] [3458]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1029 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[0:13:54.470488521] [3474]  INFO RPI libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:13:54.365083754] [3458]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3544-22656360
[0:13:54.405175545] [3474] ERROR CameraSensor camera_sensor.cpp:591 'ov5647 10-0036': Camera sensor does not support test pattern modes.
[0:13:54.468034105] [3474]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1356 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:13:54.469572692] [3458]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1029 configuring streams: (0) 1296x972-YUV420
[0:13:54.470488521] [3474]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:760 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 19
Abgebrochen
raspberrypi.cpp:760 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36 - Selected sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1296x972-pGAA
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  failed to import fd 19
Abgebrochen
```

Comment: Is Bullseye fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike Yes, it's the Full OS 32 bit version, installed updates while setting it up. Did   `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: I suggest you post on the official forum under the camera board section: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewforum.php?f=43

Comment: @CoderMode, uh thanks! gonna look into it

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by enabling Glamor graphics acceleration as specified in the top red box in the official documentation (be sure to cool down Cpu with fan and heatsink as mine reached 83°C, while running the preview). If that doesn't fix it and the libcamera-hello command does not open the video preview, you might want to control that `dtoverlay` [parameter is set](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#if-you-do-need-to-alter-the-configuration) according to your 3rd party camera module.
Moreover you can try changing the Kms driver to `fakekms`. If that doesn't work and you run on a Raspberry Pi 3, with the Bullseye OS (as in my case) check out [this thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1815677&sid=345c4185b06904d33946d3cb9d735536#p1815677https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1815677&sid=345c4185b06904d33946d3cb9d735536#p1815677) which specifies to add the `dtoverlay` to the **all** section of /boot/config.txt`.

Comment: If your answer is correct, please accept it. Otherwise this question will keep reappearing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running `sudo raspi-config`, then "Advanced Options", then "GL Driver", "then select GL (Fake KMS)". I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspberry Pi OS Buster.